# Asp.Net MVC - returing pure ViewModel from controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use Asp.Net MVC 5.0 and I'd like to "talk" with controller in my layout page. I want to call `ProfileController.GetProfileInformationViewModel` method in my Layout page to get `ProfileViewModel` class object. Is it possible without returning `ActionResult` (`View/PartialView`) and using something like `HtmlAction` in Razor ? I do not want to return any html, I want to keep it decoupled and reusable.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what is it that you want to return if not html?

Comment: pure ViewModel object (ProfileViewModel) so i could use something like Model.Surname - although not sure if it's possible - i'm new to mvc.

Comment: Try returning a `JsonResult` of your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to return something like JSON data and get this via JavaScript?

```
public JsonResult GetProfileInformationViewModel(int id)
{
    var myProfile = GetProfile(id);
    return new JsonResult(){ Data = myProfile };
}
```

Then you can use an ajax call to get the object.